# Is there something like gem for erlang?

Tags: erlang

Is there a simply plug in system like gem for erlang as I find it quite complicated to install third party software?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Comprehensive Erlang Archive Network](http://cean.process-one.net/) and [Faxien](http://erlware.org/tools/faxien/index.html) are two packages that provide an easy way to install erlang libraries.

Neither of these are bundled with erlang so first need to be installed. Then you can use them to download other software.

CEAN is available either as a library to add to an existing erlang installation or as an all-in-one install including an erlang distribution. Get CEAN from [CEAN download page](http://cean.process-one.net/downloads/) and then read the [CEAN documentation](http://cean.process-one.net/doc/) to see how to use it.

For Faxien the best is to follow the [tutorial](http://erlware.org/tools/faxien/tutorial.html). Once it's installed you can use `faxien help` to find what you can do next.

Comment: I went to these sites but it was not clear how to install them, they seem to only point to external zip files for individual packages. Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: @Zubair I've expanded the answer with some information to help get you started with either of those options.

Comment: @Gueoff - It looks interesting... I'll watch out for changes to it. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It's not difficult though to install 3rd party libraries. Just unzip/clone/whatever as a subfolder to the directory you define in the ERL_LIBS environment variable.

Answer (score 5):

There's also agner http://erlagner.org/